# EloquentJavaScript DOM recursive call in counterintuitive order

Tags: javascript, html

```js
function elt(type) {
    console.log(type); // this is the statement I am testing
    var node = document.createElement(type);
    for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        var child = arguments[i];
        if (typeof child == "string")
            child = document.createTextNode(child);
        node.appendChild(child);
    }
    return node;
}

document.getElementById("quote").appendChild(
    elt("footer", "—",
    elt("strong", "Karl Popper"),
    ", preface to the second editon of ",
    elt("em", "The Open Society and Its Enemies"),
    ", 1950")
);
```

```html
<blockquote id="quote">
    No book can ever be finished. While working on it we learn
    just enough to find it immature the moment we turn away
    from it.
</blockquote>
```

I thought that the output would be `"footer", "strong", "em"` not `"strong", "em", "footer"`. I think that when the `elt("footer", - ...., 1950)` function is called, it should print `"footer"` first then go to the arguments array by first getting `"-"`, then call `elt("strong", "Karal Popper")` until the end of the `arguments` array and return the node. The output does not do this. Can someone tell me what is going on and in what order the `elt` function is being called?

[Here’s the chapter with code](http://eloquentjavascript.net/13_dom.html).

Comment: Isn't the output `strong, em, footer`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is all due to the way that JavaScript execution works (really, most languages will work the same way). I think you mean to say the log content has `strong, em, footer`, right?

Before that top `elt` call can be made, all of the arguments need to be evaluated. Thus, `elt('strong', 'Karl Popper')` will be called before the one for `footer`. Similarly, the one for `em` would be called next, and finally `footer`.